# D3 - yAxis Ticks Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm doing the basic bar graph tutorial for D3, but the ticks for the yAxis aren't showing up even though the line does.  This question has been asked a lot, but I still haven't found an answer for my specific situation.  Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>

<svg class="chart"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var width = 960, height = 500
var barWidth = width / data.length

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d)])
  .range([height, 0])

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

var groups = chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i * barWidth}, 0)`)

groups.append('rect')
  .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d))
  .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)

groups.append('text')
  .attr('x', barWidth / 2)
  .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)
  .text(d => d)

</script>
```

Fun fact: when I append the axis using axisBottom instead of axisLeft, I can see the axis with its ticks (obviously not oriented correctly).  Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Add a fiddle to be able to solve it quickly

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the axis generator creates an axis which, when called (using `call`), is painted at the `0,0` position:

> Regardless of orientation, axes are always rendered at the origin.

So, you need to `translate` the axis, moving it a little bit to the right:

```
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")//magic number, change it at will
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

Here is the demo:

```html
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.barText {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>

<svg class="chart"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var width = 500, height = 300
var barWidth = width / data.length

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d)])
  .range([height - 10, 0])

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

var groups = chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i * barWidth + 30}, 0)`)

groups.append('rect')
  .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d))
  .attr('height', (d) => height - 10 - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)

groups.append('text')
 .attr("class", "barText")
  .attr('x', barWidth / 2)
 .attr('y', d=> yScale(d) + 16)
  .attr('height', (d) => height - 10 - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)
  .text(d => d)
 
 chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

</script>
```

PS: You have some additional issues in your code, that you can improve (here, I'm simply answering your question):

1. Your code lacks all the paddings (left, right, top, bottom);
2. You should use a scale for x positioning
3. You don't need to calculate the bar width, `bandwidth()` does that automatically.
4. Template literals don't work on IE

Answer (score 0):

I not an expert but I think I figured it out. You were not assiging approriate x,y for your .text()... I have modified code that works for me... See the JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wpfkm6dn/2/

code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>

<svg class="chart"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var width = 960, height = 500
var barWidth = width / data.length

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d)])
  .range([height, 0])

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

var groups = chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i * barWidth}, 0)`)

groups.append('rect')
  .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d))
  .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)

groups.append('text')
  .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d) + 20)
  .attr('x', barWidth / 2)
  .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d))
  .attr('width', barWidth - 1)
  .text(d => d)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved it yet but I've taken another approach. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrqmqcph/1/)

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var svg = d3.select(".chart");
// we need to set a margin so that the yAxis has space to display
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
// these variables are assigned such that the margin is already deducted
var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var padding = 5; //5 px padding between bars
var barWidth = width / data.length - padding;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // here we can just call d3.max(data) because data is an array
  .range([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5));

g.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) { return (barWidth + padding) * i; })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d); })
  .attr('width', barWidth)
  .attr('height', function(d) { return height - yScale(d); });
```

Based off of https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304